# removeAt function is not working inside "For" function Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to check if an item belongs to calendar, if not I want to remove it but it is not working.

Firstly the process of calculation works just fine and I tested if it gets past the "if" function that contains removeAt() function (it works and it prints the "removing $i") but somehow it does not remove the element, the List returns same as beginning. What is the issue?

```
List<CalendarItem> items(List<CalendarItem> itemsinit,User user){
  print('FS: ${itemsinit.length}');
  if(searchbydate){
   for(int i=0;i<itemsinit.length;i++){

    FetchUser(itemsinit[i].author)..then((res){

      isuserfollowed(user.id,res.id)..then((result){

        if(user.shouldshowuserinfo(res,result) == 'public'){

          FetchPublicUser(res.id)..then((res23){

            if(doesitembelong(res23,itemsinit[i].item) == false){
              print('removing $i');
              itemsinit.removeAt(i);
            };
          });
        };
      });
    });
  }
}
  print('LS: ${itemsinit.length}');
  return itemsinit;
}
```

Comment: print `itemsinit.length` after remove an Item from index and see before and after length value. If you see the value is decreased you must miss `setState{}` to call for your UI update.

Comment: Length stays the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FetchUser`, `isuserfollowed`, and `FetchPublicUser` all appear to return `Future`s. You are not awaiting these `Future`s but instead calling `.then` on them. This is a problem because your `items` function will return before the callbacks to `.then` are even run.

Make the function `async` and convert the `.then` calls to `await`s.

```dart
Future<List<CalendarItem>> items(
    List<CalendarItem> itemsinit, User user) async {
  if (searchbydate) {
    for (int i = 0; i < itemsinit.length; i++) {
      final res = await FetchUser(itemsinit[i].author);
      final result = await isuserfollowed(user.id, res.id);
      if (user.shouldshowuserinfo(res, result) == 'public') {
        final res23 = await FetchPublicUser(res.id);
        if (doesitembelong(res23, itemsinit[i].item) == false) {
          print('removing $i');
          itemsinit.removeAt(i);
          i--;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return itemsinit;
}
```

Comment: It was connected to a Future function ,so i never thought it would need an extra work . It works now,Thanks a lot!

Comment: @umarbeyoglu Be aware that it is not without problems deleting stuff from the list you are going though at the same time. E.g. if you are removing elements in this code, you are going to skip elements (since you are removing the element at `i` and the next element in the list will now become `i`, but you are then `i++` in your loop) since the list will shrink when calling `removeAt`. A solution here would be to decrease `i` by one in your if-statement where you are making a removal to ensure your loop does not skip the element.

Comment: Edited the code to reflect @julemand101's advice

Comment: @mmcdon20 Great. Alternative, you could do: `itemsinit.removeAt(i--);` but I like it is clear that we make the subtraction so just let your answer be as it is. :)

Comment: @julemand101 I am aware you can do that as well, but it isn't always clear to readers that the decrement happens after passing in `i` to `removeAt`.